# employer association-union govt efficient and democratic?

Tags: government, modern, governance

This is for a modern isekai (other world) story, not necessarily scifi as its not focused on technology.

---

*Definitions:*

**Union**--organization of workers who have come together to achieve common goals, such as protecting the integrity of their trade, improving safety standards, and attaining better wages, benefits (such as vacation, health care, and retirement), and working conditions through the increased bargaining power wielded by solidarity among workers.

**Employer Association**--collective organization of manufacturers, retailers, or other employers of wage labor. Employers' organizations seek to coordinate the behavior of their member companies in matters of mutual interest, such as during negotiations with trade unions or government bodies. Employers' organizations operate like trade unions and promote the economic and social interests of its member organisations.

---

Just as the Employer association represents the businesses and the unions represent the workers in the industries negotiating with the specific employer association, my govt idea is to have a national version of this:

The national employers association would consist of all employers in the nation and the national union would consist of all the workers in the nation.  One may need to choose if they could belong to both?  They would be two separate and free organizations, but they are empowered to negotiate with each other to create binding laws for the nation within their purview (eg defence, social welfare, trade). The court system could have a mediator (binding only if both parties agree, as opposed to arbitrator) witness.

---

Please let me know what you think.  Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: A third leg could be either the interest groups (eg free speech/ACLU, Green Energy) involved in specific ordinances or laws, or a national interest group federation.

Comment: Define efficient and democratic.

Comment: ???? Negotiations between the unions (such as the German [IG Metall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IG_Metall)) and the (collective body representing the) employers are very common in Europe. Look up [social market economy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_market_economy). No, they do not take decisions regarding defence, social welfare, or trade; such matters are entirely outside the scope of the relationship between employers and employees. They take decisions about the relationship between the employers and the employess (wages, hours worked, workplace conditions, pensions).

Answer (score 5):

You're missing several major demographics.

You're completely missing the small businesses, the shopkeepers, prostitutes, builders, tradesmen and others who are neither employers nor employed. When they unite to set working conditions it's called a cartel not a union. You might be surprised by how much of your economy that represents.

Next up the students, everyone from the current age of voting through to graduation. While included in our current systems they do not fall under one of your headings so they don't get represented.

Now to the retirees, surely through all their years they're worth representing somewhere in the system, but now they're neither employees, nor employers and fall out of the system

Of course you can suggest that those not in work are not useful to the society and as such not deserving of a say in the system, thus creating yourself a glorious dystopia based around the needs of companies and their workers and everyone else is forgotten.

Comment: Really not going for dystopian.  The independent contractors  and Gig workers (eg Doordash) could be part of a IC union (eg SAGAFTRA for actors).  Small businesses would be covered under the same union covered by big business (eg AFLCIO) or a collective small business union.  As for students, pretty sure they have unions.  The unemployed could join the aforementioned IC union.

Comment: @리주민 dystopian is more fun though! If you really think this through carefully and make sure everyone is represented under only one heading, then all you've really done is redrawn constituency boundaries with a different set of rules. Right now we use geographical boundaries, you're asking to use economic ones.

Comment: @Separatix Dystopian may be more fun, particularly since its quite prevalent in fiction.  Utopian and meh-topian(?) are not done enough, IMHO ;)

Comment: @리주민 Utopian isn't done because it's dull. Interesting stories are about overcoming adversity, utopia has no adversity. We live in a meh-topia, no need to reinvent that one. The fun is in the failed utopia, an attempt was made and here are the people it failed for, or the weakness in the system that allowed someone to subvert or exploit it.

Comment: I get what you're saying about the meh-topia.  The govt plot was going to be a sub-plot.  The govt would just be in the background, like for negotiations with the mc or on the telly. Similar to how other stories don't focus heavily on the politics, but you know they're there.

Answer (score 1):

### *Very* definitely no.

Your proposed system, while interesting, suffers from three huge problems.

#### I: The factions aren't monolithic.

While it's very easy to assume that the Bourgeoisie and the Proletariat are monolithic groups, this is not the case. Labor isn't necessarily worth the same between regions or industries, and things that teachers care about (e.g. the ability to discipline students) aren't the same as what metalworkers care about (e.g. workplace safety, hazard pay, etc.)

These differing interests and factions mean that monolithic groups representing *all* the Bourgeoisie and *all* the Proletariat would not be able to internally agree on what they want.

### II: Monopolization

Basically, the way the modern economy works is that if the employees and the employers can't come to an agreement the employees ultimately vote with their feet, moving to another employer who *will* give them a fair deal. This is impossible under your system.

If you have monolithic groups representing *all* the employers and *all* the employees you end up with one of two results. On the one hand, the employers use their monopoly on employment to force the employees to work under untenable conditions. On the other, the employees use their monopoly on labor to force the employers to pay ridiculously high salaries that force them to raise the prices on their products, creating a hyperinflation feedback loop.

Either way, the system soon breaks down, and groups of workers and employers break off and form a free market.

### III: Not everybody falls into these categories

People aren't necessarily either employers or employees. There are a lot of contractors and small business owners out there who don't fall into either group. While the amount tends to vary at any given time, it's always a surprisingly large percentage of the population. Under your system you'll end up with a sort of "tyranny of the majority" in which the unions will force their will upon the small business owners and contractors. A good real life example of this is how the barbers' union recently forced the dog groomers to join their union, even though the dog-grooming ecosystem is almost completely disparate.

Comment: All democratic systems are vulnerable to tyranny of the majority, many don't even need a majority, so that's not really a valid argument against this one.

Answer (score 0):

**Look at Iceland.**

Union rates are over 90%. Collective bargaining agreements set minimum wage, benefits, and other social policies. The Icelandic Confederation of Labor consists of 2/3rds of the workers in the country.

Near universal unionization is practical policy. Consolidation into a nearly universal single union is certainly possible. Highly developed countries have these policies. Research the economics of these countries, then simply further consolidate.

**Look at Communism.**

Communist countries theoretically had 100% unionization rates, although in practice there were multiple factions and sub-divisions within the greater worker councils.

**Trusts and Cartels**

There is no historical example of a united group of employers. The closest would be various cartels. Look to OPEC for a modern example, or the massive Trusts of 19th century America for examples of coordinated activity by very large businesses.

A universal cartel versus a universal union sounds like a recipe for class warfare, rather than a utopia. That could be interesting, as well, though.

A utopian universal cartel would need some strong changes in social ethics. Otherwise, a purely competitive, profit-maximizing business environment would lead to vicious monopolization.

**Government?**

Perhaps you could have some sort of socially-conscious business model, together with very strong regulation from a central government? Or is the goal to remove the government entirely, and have rule by union + employer coordination?

https://www.asi.is/english/

https://wol.iza.org/articles/the-labor-market-in-iceland/long